# Vim 8.0.69 not respecting BackupDir and Directory settings

Tags: vim

Is anyone else having issues with the latest version of VIM on Windows not honoring the `backupdir` and `directory` settings in `_vimrc`? I'm currently running on Windows 10 and have seen this behavior on WinXP, but have not tried on Win10 yet. I know that my `_vimrc` is getting used because other settings are taking affect. I've tried a few suggestions, and have posted to the `vim-use` forum here: [VIM 8.0.69 not honoring "backupdir" and "directory"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_use/bdir%7Csort:relevance/vim_use/DXw-tJodPwY/U0neSHT0DwAJ), but have not found a resolution. The backup and swap files are appearing in the location of the edited file.

Here's the interesting bits of my `_vimrc` file with comments:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

" Create the folder if it does not exists
if !isdirectory("c:\\temp\\vim_backups")
    call mkdir("c:\\temp\\vim_backups", "p")
endif   

" This worked in vim74, but not 8.0.69
set backupdir=c:\temp\vim_backups,.      " Also tried bdir=...
set directory=c:\temp\vim_backups,.      " and dir=...


" Tried this as well, to no avail
"set nobackup
"set nowritebackup

set lines=50
set columns=180
set nowrap
set number
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set autoindent
set ic"ignore case

" Other non-interesting bits removed
```

I'll likely rollback to vim74 which has worked reliably for me up until now.

** Edit 1 **

Added portion of script that creates the `vim_backup` folder.

** Edit 2 **

My bad, I think what I was seeing were the `undo` files. I ran across a posting discussing the `undodir` setting. I realize now that the turds I was seeing were actually `undo` files. Things seem to be working as expected now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It works for me on Linux, but I haven't tried Windows. Can you verify that the option is set to what you want with `:set dir? bdir?`?

Comment: Do you have write rights on that directory?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Yes, they are set, however they don't seem to be getting honored.

Comment: @romainl: I do have rights to wite to that directory because I created it myself, and also it was the first thing I checked. Actually it gets created from my _vimrc. I forgot to include those lines in my post. I'll add that so things are more clear.

Comment: See *** Edit 2***. My bad, sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: I'll suggest answering your own question [as a separate answer] and puritanically removing the word "turds" ;^) 2¢, ymmv.